# Invalid Column Name error with Hibernate createSQLquery

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

This is a smaller version of a larger query I'm trying to get working. When I run the query I get the following error. I've tried removing as much of the query as I can to try to find the guilty column, but haven't had any success.
I'm using Spring 3.2.1, Hibernate 3.6, and Oracle 11g

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3711)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:2763)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getBigDecimal(OracleResultSet.java:368)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.DecimalTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(DecimalTypeDescriptor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
```

Query:

```
String query = "SELECT d.ID as {d.id}, d.DETAIL_ORDER as {d.detailOrder}, g.ID as {g.id}, g.NAME as {g.name} " +
    "FROM EVAL_MASTER_EVAL_DETAIL d " +
    "JOIN EVAL_QUESTION_GROUP g ON d.GROUP_ID = g.ID " +
    "WHERE d.ACTIVE = 'Y' " +
    "AND d.MASTER_EVAL_ID =  :evalId" + 
    " ORDER BY d.DETAIL_ORDER ASC"; 

    details = session.createSQLQuery(query).addEntity("d", EvalMasterEvalDetail.class)
    .addEntity("g", EvalQuestionGroup.class).setParameter("evalId", evalId).list();
```

Resulting Hibernate Query:

```
Hibernate: SELECT d.ID as ID29_0_, d.DETAIL_ORDER as DETAIL5_29_0_, g.ID as ID34_1_, g.NAME as NAME34_1_ FROM EVAL_MASTER_EVAL_DETAIL d JOIN EVAL_QUESTION_GROUP g ON d.GROUP_ID = g.ID WHERE d.ACTIVE = 'Y' AND d.MASTER_EVAL_ID =  ? ORDER BY d.DETAIL_ORDER ASC
```

Mappings (to verify names)

```
<hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="org.anes.surveys.domain.EvalMasterEvalDetail" table="EVAL_MASTER_EVAL_DETAIL">
            <id name="id" type="big_decimal">
                <column name="ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
                <generator class="sequence-identity" >
                    <param name="sequence">EVAL_MASTER_EVAL_DETAIL_SEQ</param>
                </generator>
            </id>
            <many-to-one name="evalQuestionGroup" class="org.anes.surveys.domain.EvalQuestionGroup" fetch="select">
                <column name="GROUP_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
            </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="evalMasterEvaluation" class="org.anes.surveys.domain.EvalMasterEvaluation" fetch="select">
        <column name="MASTER_EVAL_ID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
            <property name="detailOrder" type="big_decimal">
                <column name="DETAIL_ORDER" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="active" type="string">
                <column name="ACTIVE" length="1" not-null="true" />
            </property>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.anes.surveys.domain.EvalQuestionGroup" table="EVAL_QUESTION_GROUP">
        <id name="id" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence-identity" >
                <param name="sequence">EVAL_QUESTION_GROUP_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="evalMasterEvalDetails" table="EVAL_MASTER_EVAL_DETAIL" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="GROUP_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="org.anes.surveys.domain.EvalMasterEvalDetail" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

EDIT:
Tried the following and still get invalid column error. ACTIVE & d.active are strings.

```
String query = "SELECT ACTIVE as {d.active} " +
                "FROM EVAL_MASTER_EVAL_DETAIL";
details = session.createSQLQuery(query).addEntity("d", EvalMasterEvalDetail.class).list();

String query = "SELECT d.ID " +
        "FROM EVAL_MASTER_EVAL_DETAIL d ";
details = session.createSQLQuery(query).addEntity("d", EvalMasterEvalDetail.class).list();

String query = "SELECT ID " +
        "FROM EVAL_MASTER_EVAL_DETAIL";
details = session.createSQLQuery(query).addEntity("d", EvalMasterEvalDetail.class).list();
```

This works, but I only get scalar values:

```
String query = "SELECT ID " +
        "FROM EVAL_MASTER_EVAL_DETAIL";
details = session.createSQLQuery(query).list();
```

Comment: Have you tried running the query to return just a single column?

Comment: You don't have `MASTER_EVAL_ID` in the mapping, and you are using it in `AND d.MASTER_EVAL_ID =  :evalId`, that might be the one, can't be sure though.

Comment: Try to execute generated SQL directly to Oracle.

Comment: hibernate is generating the query with the metadata of yours mappings, however the physical DB does not match to you mapping you should run the generated query and search wich column have a wrong name

Comment: Sorry, MASTER_EVAL_ID was missing in the code I posted. It's in my mapping file. I edited my post. The query runs fine in Oracle. Also, I checked all the column names in the mapping files against the tables and they match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing.

-I used HQL instead of my native SQL (reference the object fields instead of db columns)

-Created a new domain class with getters and setters to define/hold the results of my query (class contains fields from 5 different objects/tables)

```
public class EvalForm {
    private BigDecimal detailId;
    private BigDecimal detailOrder;
    private BigDecimal groupId;
    private String groupName;
}
```

-Used my new class' field names as the column aliases

```
String query = "SELECT d.id as detailId, d.detailOrder as detailOrder, g.id as groupId, g.name as groupName....
```

-Added setResultTransformer to point to my new class

```
details = session.createQuery(query).setParameter("evalId", evalId).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(EvalForm.class)).list();
```

The result? Perfect for JSON output.

```
[{"detailId":44,"detailOrder":0,"groupId":128,"groupName":"My dope name"},{"detailId":42,"detailOrder":1,"groupId":68,"groupName":"qGroup AJAX"},{"detailId":81,"detailOrder":2,"groupId":68,"groupName":"qGroup AJAX"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all column aliases. Ie change:

```
d.ID as {d.id}
```

to just

```
d.ID
```

etc.

I've never seen such HQL syntax. It might be valid, but it's certainly unnecessary.

Comment: The aliases reference the java object. Doesn't the addEntity string refer to the {aliases}? I thought those were needed to avoid returning scalar values. I updated my post with a couple more ways I tried (with and without the references), but no luck.